# Laço de repetição for em C

Tags: c, for

Tenho que fazer o seguinte exercício:

*Leia 3 valores inteiros e ordene-os em ordem crescente. No final, mostre os valores em ordem crescente, uma linha em branco e em seguida, os valores na sequência como foram lidos.*

A parte da ordenação dos números consegui. Preciso agora exibir o índice (contador) fora do for.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main() {

int n, i, maior, menor, meio;

scanf("%d", &n);
maior = n; menor = n; meio = n;

for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n > maior) {
        maior = n;
    } else if (n < menor) {
        menor = n;
    } else {
        meio = n;
    }
}

  printf("%d\n", menor);
  printf("%d\n", meio);
  printf("%d\n", maior);
  printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução é o uso de vetores. Segue o exemplo:

> Para usar o código, basta copiar os trechos dentro das caixas de código e colá-los em ordem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    const int NUM = 3; // quantidade de valores lidos
```

Tem **2** vetores com **3** espaços o `n` e `ord`. A variável `n` irá armazenar os números inseridos, e `ord` irá guardar os números ordenados de forma crescente.

```
    int n[NUM];
    int ord[NUM];

    int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<NUM; x++){
        scanf("%d",&n[x]);
        ord[x] = n[x];
    }
```

O valores lidos em `n` já são inseridos em `ord`, assim facilitará quando for ordenar o vetor.

```
    int min; // numero mínimo
    int pos; // posição do número mínimo
    for(x=0; x<NUM; x++){
        min = ord[x];
        pos = -1;
```

A variável `min` sempre irá receber a posição `x` de `ord`, pois será sempre o primeiro número do vetor, sendo assim o menor número encontrado até o momento.
E `pos` recebe **-1** para indicar que não está relacionado com nenhuma posição do vetor.

```
        for(y=x; y<NUM; y++){
```

Quando a encontrar outro valor menor que `min`, é registrada seu valor e sua posição.

```
            if(ord[y] < min){
                min = ord[y];
                pos = y;
            }
        }
```

Quando como encontrou um número menor que o `min`, `pos` passa a ser maior ou igual a **0**, então entra nessa condição para fazer a troca de valores.

```
        if(pos >= 0){
            ord[pos] = ord[x];
            ord[x] = min;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", ord[0], ord[1], ord[2]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Faz tempo não mexo com C. Mas parece que teu código não faz o mínimo necessário para a ordenação: Ler **3** valores. Há apenas um `scanf` e fora de qualquer *loop*. Não sei como você testou a ordenação, para chegar a conclusão que funciona.

Acho que você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
int n1,n2,n3;

scanf("%d", &n1);
scanf("%d", &n2);
scanf("%d", &n3);
```

Após isso, você pode ordenar os três valores. Porem, o exercício pede que os números sejam exibidos na ordem original também. Então, uma solução é fazer um backup dos valores originais, algo assim:

```
int ord1 = n1, ord2 = n2, ord3 = n3;
```

Ai então você pode ordenar os valores `ord1`, `ord2` e `ord3`, e mostrar os **6** valores, como pede o exercício.

Comment: Seu código lé os valores mas não ordena em ordem crescente como é pedido, quando for escrever os números, ambos serão na mesma ordem.

Comment: Imaginei que o autor da pergunta não tinha problema com a ordenação, já que ele mesmo afirmou que funcionava. :D

Comment: É que ordenar 2 ou 3 números, chega a ser fácil, mas acima disse não é viável com condições, então ose usa algorítimos de ordenação. Se em uma resposta VC puder dar soluções e melhorias, isso resulta a qualidade de sua resposta.